# Coding a parser in Python

Tags: python, parsing, config

I'm trying to make a config reader in Python. The config has the following structure:

```
@section:
    property = 'value'
end

@section2:
    property2 = 'value'
end
```

The config is managed using two functions:

```
getValue(file, section, property)
setValue(file, section, property, newvalue)
```

But I don't know how to do the parser. Help plz :\

Comment: Do you know about https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html

Comment: This is going to be closed, because you don't have any code. Please read the help files.

Comment: How are those two functions defined? It would pretty much dictate what your parser needs to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was interesting. This should work perfectly. I wasn't sure whether to strip out the single quotes you had next to your values, but I decided to take them out for cleanliness of output.

```
with open('configfile.cfg') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

    config = {}
    current_section = None
    for line in data:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == 'end' or not line:
            continue

        if line.startswith('@'):
            current_section = line[1:-1]
            config[current_section] = {}
        else:
            key, value = line.split('=')
            config[current_section][key.strip()] = value.strip().strip("'")

    print(config)
```

For future reference, it's a lot easier to help if you give a small bit of actual data and then describe the data, rather than giving names that are types. For example, I used this as a config file:

```
@section:
    red = '3three'
end

@section2:
    blue = '4four'
    green = '5five'
end
```

and here's the output dict for that config file:

```
{'section': {'red': '3three'}, 'section2': {'blue': '4four', 'green': '5five'}}
```